# Paginate or turn down count of Coderwall protips washing up in dashboard deluge

Tags: coderwall

Where do you go to turn off or limit how many default protips show up when you view your dashboard on Coderwall?

When you log into the site, depending on what networks you've signed up to, you see a whole long page of protips. It takes a while to see the page load and render just the tips.

Right now it dumps up a count of say 100 at first go. That's quite the plenty. Something more sane like a handful of bananas would be a salad of nice.